# Behavior of velocity of a particle as $t$ tends to $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, classical-mechanics

Let $r(t) = (\cos (4t), \sin (4t), t^2).$ We have to find the velocity of the particle at time $t$ and describe what happens when $t \to \infty$.

Since $r(t) = (\cos (4t), \sin (4t), t^2)$, $$v(t) = r'(t) = (-4\sin(4t),4\cos(4t),2t)$$

Thus as $t \to \infty$, the $z$ component of velocity tends to $\infty$. Is the explanation correct?

Comment: Yes, seems fine. Perhaps mention that for all $t$ the $x$ and $y$ components of velocity are bounded between $-4$ and $4$

Comment: @bounceback what does it mean $\infty$ velocity?

Comment: If you are familiar with the concept of limits (Calculus 1 or equiv.), you will appreciate that the velocity is never infinite, but is forever increasing, and this can be formalised via the usual $\epsilon$-argument to define what it means for $v \to \infty$

Comment: @bounceback got it thank you.

Comment: Not a useful question. Why do you think your answer might not be correct?